# Are there any alternative GPS modules for the Pentax k30 than the O-GPS1?

Tags: pentax, gps

Are there any alternative GPS modules for the Pentax k30 than the O-GPS1?

Comment: I have a third party GPS for my Nikon made by "Promote".  You might check whether they also make units for Pentax.

Comment: Hm, on their page they say it is not. It seems that Promote only supports some Nikon cameras.

Answer (score 2):

A true alternative, one that supports the full features of the O-GPS1 module, is very unlikely as the biggest thing lost would probably be the astrotrace feature (one that I miss with my switch to Nikon). There are, however, some options out there:

- [Jobo PhotoGPS](http://www.jobo.com/photoGPS.486.0.html) sits on your hotshoe and records when it gets the voltage signal that is there to trip a flash. Their manual is available for download.
- [Eye-Fi](http://support.eye.fi/features/geo/what-is-geotagging/) can do some geotagging. It would depend on the use of an Android phone.

In both cases, it requires some level of processing to update the image with the GPS information. The first one is a lot more manual, the second one less so, but it's a need. If you have the O-GPS1 unit, it just happens, something to keep in mind.